# Is there a mistake in this sentence? : "Ms Park was left the money by her former husband, from whom she was divorced in 2005."

Tags: grammar, sentence, sentence-patterns

Namely - is "was left the money" a correct structure here? Wouldn't "has left the money" make sense here also?

Comment: Her ex left the money to her, so '[she] has left the money' does not mean the same.

Comment: @KateBunting so this sentence is logically and gramatically correct - the one with "was", right?

Comment: Yes. It's the passive version of "Ms. Park's husband left her the money..." The passive voice was presumably used here to alter the syntax such that the "whom" in the subordinate clause would be close to its antecedent. Note that the indirect object, not the direct object, in the active version becomes the subject in the passive version. This is somewhat unusual and could help explain why you found it questionable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Ms Park was left the money" ... someone left money to her.

"MsPark has left the money" ... she left money to someone else.  In this case you would not say "by her former husband" but you might say "to her former husband".

Comment: "Has left the money by her former husband" means that Ms Park placed the money next to her former husband. Changing the sentence from passive to active alters the meaning completely.

Comment: @AndrewLeach ... I'm laughing, can you tell?

Comment: the meaning of this structure sure is funny, @GEdgar